# Does Trish actually have super-powers?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, jessica-jones-2015

I'm half-way through season 3. They've just found

> the tanker full of body parts

Trish is talking and acting as though she has super-powers, but I'm not clear on whether she does actually have them.

We got shown her doing a long training montage around various parkour skills, which made me think that she doesn't ACTUALLY have any powers - she's just trained herself really hard, and thus become very fit, strong and agile, and we already knew that she'd trained hard at Krav Maga, in season 1.

Further question would then be does she *think* she has powers (i.e. she's deluding herself), or is she *bluffing* that she has powers (i.e. she's knowingly pretending that she does), or is she just coincidentally using ambiguous dialogue to refer to her top-flight martial arts training as being "powerful".

Comment: Chunky spoilers - https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Trish_Walker Yes, she has powers.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really want to read through the wikis until I'd caught up to now. Thanks for confirming (and warning) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes

First, she learns physical skills incredibly fast. Whether this is a consequence of her other powers or something distinct isn't clear, but her trainer thought she was on performance-enhancing drugs due to how fast she learned. Some of her physical skills are possible in the real world—for a person who has been training since they were a child. She picked them up in less than a year.

She has incredible reflexes, although they are limited by her strength being that of a normal athletic human. She was able to catch her phone with the toe of her high-heeled shoe. It took her a bit of time to master those reflexes, but I assume she could eventually do it reliably. In connection, she must have incredibly precise proprioception. Catching a falling object on a flat surface that small is almost impossible. Catching it on the curved surface of a shoe requires extreme precision.

She's not exactly as brittle as a normal human, either. She jumped at least 50 feet out of a building and landed on her feet, with no apparent injuries. Even accepting that her reflexes enable the landing part, the fact that she was unharmed suggests durability somewhat beyond the usual.

While it's not entirely clear if this constitutes a power, she was able to cause some quite severe injuries with only her nails, which seemed possibly beyond what an average human can do, and possibly attributable to somewhat enhanced strength or her nails being somewhat harder or sharper than the human norm (not as disconnected as it might seem, if we consider her alias; see below).

Finally, she can see with almost no light. Night looks like day to her. This, obviously, is something the average person cannot do, no matter how many carrots they eat.

This is why her comics alias, barely mentioned on the show, is Hellcat: she's got excellent reflexes, can see in the dark, and always lands on her feet.

These powers may not seem like much compared to Jessica's ability to lift a car, or the destructive capabilities, speed, or invulnerability of someone like Captain Marvel or Thor, but they'd still let her get the better of almost any normal human being or small group thereof in a close-up fight without any trouble.

Comment: They would make her as powerful as Black Widow or Hawkeye though, if not more so.

Comment: @Sarriesfan - Although they are not formally described as having superpowers, Black Widow and Hawkeye's abilities are in fact beyond what  humans are actually capable of in the real world, much as Steve Rogers was frequently described as being at the peak of human potential despite clearly being beyond it. However, based on what Trish's powers are, with several years of intensive SHIELD-level training she would indeed be more formidable in many respects.

Comment: @Adamant, just FYI, carrots do nothing whatsoever for night vision. That was a propoganda smokescreen created by the British during WWII to hide the fact that they'd invented radar.

Comment: Link: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/a-wwii-propaganda-campaign-popularized-the-myth-that-carrots-help-you-see-in-the-dark-28812484/

Comment: I'm well aware. That's the joke.